# Permission of uploads folder

Tags: security, permissions, server, apache

My Wordpress site was hacked today. When I investigated, I noticed that there were some malicious files under wp-content/uploads/ folder. I had set the permission of uploads folder to 777 for uploading images from the administration interface. And, I believe this was abused using the possible misconfiguration of the Apache server.

What should the permission of uploads folder be?

How should Apache be configured in order to enable image uploading through the administration interface and prevent accessing the content of the folder by unauthorized people?

Comment: Is that shared hosting or dedicated server/vps?

Comment: it's a shared hosting. but the technical skills of the company is quite limited. i can't trust them.

Comment: 777 is especially evil on shared hosting, because it means that other customers on that server can write to your files as long as the hoster doesn't implement additional security measures. 755 should be enough in any case under the prerequisite that the user and group settings of your files are correct.

Comment: Apache is running as www-data. WP organizes the images in separate folders according to the year and month. WP creates folders for every year and month, they all belong to www-data and they are 777 too! Will I be able to upload images through the WP administration interface if I change the folders to 755?